# Xcode App Property List Path - App Home Directory?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, path, directory, plist

I'm new to objective-c and would like to understand how to set a file path to the app's home directory. For testing and development I've been manually putting in the path of the property list on my hard drive but now I want to bundle it - or just archive and distribute it to test as an application without Xcode test building... I've been using this...

```
NSString* pListPath = @"/Users/-----/Saves/Resourcing/resourcingProperties.plist";
NSMutableDictionary *pListDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pListPath];
NSMutableDictionary* interfaceKeysDictionary = [pListDictionary valueForKey:@"Interface Keys"];
NSMutableDictionary* valueSavesDictionary = [pListDictionary valueForKey:@"Value Saves"];
```

How do I use the path of app's home directory once the application is bundled as a stand-alone app in my Application folder?

Comment: What do you mean by "the app's home directory"? Apps don't have a home directory. Only users have a home directory. Do you mean the user's home directory? Or do you mean the absolute path to the application? If the latter, what are you trying to use the path for? You generally will want to use various NSBundle methods for getting resources from your app's bundle, for example.

Comment: Yeah I meant how to access the property list in a bundle. I could look into NSBundles methods for finding the property list path, unless you have any suggestions? And yes I mean the apps path. Not the users home directory.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want inside the bundle? Is it just the Info.plist? Or do you want a specific resource, like an image in the <app>/Contents/Resources/" directory? I can give you an exact answer, but I need to know what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you look in the original question, I just want to set an NSString to the path of the property list. Lets say it's named MyInfo.plist, I want the path of that property list assigned to a NSString, so I can make a few dictionaries inside it.

Comment: OK, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you're trying to do, you don't want or need to read the plist file directly. You just call:

```
NSBundle* mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle]; // or [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier]
NSDictionary* infoDict = [mainBundle infoDictionary];
NSMutableDictionary* plistDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:infoDict];
```

You can then add to it in code as you see fit.